# Google AJAX Feed API will work for blog posts

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-plugins, xhtml

I can use a page or multiple pages to display user's info with their most recent post. Any ideas on how to approach this? Are there any jQuery plugins available for this?

Can I incorporate "Google AJAX Feed API" for this. I've not used this before. How to proceed??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

js has no access to browser history, only to single window(tab) history and has no local storages on client side. You need to work with history on the server side.

Comment: can you pls explain bit more on handling history on server side?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean a simple RSS viewer for the RSS feed of the blog:

like this:
[Google code playground](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?exp=feeds#feed_control)